# sql. syntax select Perform Arithmetic Operations

Tags: sql-server

i want  Perform Arithmetic Operations in select syntac sql like 10 minus 5 = 5 but my select not work.

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in ) as late, DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,off_duty, clock_out ) as Early, late - Early as jajalan from kkpsurabaya
```

[look image pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lenYM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the result of the function in the same select because  [you cannot refer to an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975749/reference-an-alias-elsewhere-in-the-select-list) outside of SELECT and ORDER BY because of the way a query is parsed. You could call the same function multiple times:

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in ) as late, 
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,off_duty, clock_out ) as Early, 
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in )- DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,off_duty, clock_out ) as jajalan 
from kkpsurabaya
```

or a common-table-expreession:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,on_duty, clock_in ) as Late,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,off_duty, clock_out ) as Early,
    t.*
    FROM kkpsurabaya t  
)
SELECT Late, Early, Late - Early as jajalan
FROM CTE
```