# SQL Server: Calculations

Tags: sql-server

**What is wrong with the following code**

I am trying to calculate commissions based on an existing column and loading into a temp table, when I run the query, it gives me an error saying - Invalid column name 'Multiplier'.

---

```
SELECT *, Multiplier =
    Case PRODUCTNAME 
    When  'Voice' then 2.4
    When  'Cable' then 4.8
    Else 1
    END,
    Multiplier * COMP_RATE as Commission
  into #CommissionsFTMJul18
  FROM [DBPO_TRANS].[dbo].[CREDITS]
```

Comment: You need a nested query where you define `Multiplier` or recalculate the value of `Multiplier` for the column where you are trying to use that value. Duplicate of [Reference an alias elsewhere in the SELECT list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11975749/1260204)

Comment: I guess the case statement doesnt have a column name specified. That might be an error. Try giving a column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define the name multiplier and use it in a calculation in the same statement. Just use two `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT *, Multiplier =
    Case PRODUCTNAME 
    When  'Voice' then 2.4
    When  'Cable' then 4.8
    Else 1
    END,
    Case PRODUCTNAME 
    When  'Voice' then 2.4
    When  'Cable' then 4.8
    Else 1
    END * COMP_RATE as Commission
  into #CommissionsFTMJul18
  FROM [DBPO_TRANS].[dbo].[CREDITS]
```

Comment: Thanks, It works...